# How do we find the surface charge density of a charged conductor?

Tags: classical-electrodynamics

It is mentioned in Feynman volume 2 that it is quite algorithmic , where the surface charge density is first guessed then check whether it is equipotential at the metal surface..
My question is for a better way.

Comment: Are you referring to inverse problems in electrostatics?

Comment: Well for finding surface charge density there is no specific methods but for conductor there are two conditions one of which is that the potential on the surface of conductor is constant and the other one is that electric field inside the conductor is zero(uniqueness theorem).But for different type of problems you will use different methods.

Comment: I have no clue about inverse problems in electrostatics..

Answer (score 0):

That’s how nature does it. The charges sense the field configuration of the surface: if its not an equipotential, then there are components of the electric force in the surface. Since it’s a conductor, the charges can and do move in response to those. That reduces the potential differences. Repeat for a few tiny fractions of a second until done.

Comment: Yeah I got that but my question is for giving surface charge density as a function of geometry of the conductor

Comment: Like for an 3D ellipsoid conductor with equation x squared by a squared plus y squared by b square plus z squared by c square equals 1   . The surface charge density is Q by (4 pi abc)*[( x squared by a power 4 and cyclic for y and z )^-0.5]. So is there a similar formula for a different geometry..